# Concatenate multiple rows data in single cell in a WEBI report

Tags: business-objects, webi

Need advice for a webi report in BO 4.1  Sorry about the alignment.

I have a report as follow:

| Country | Agent | Customer | Products |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UK | Mo | Sara | Bag |
| UK | Adam | Jill | Bag |
| UK | Tim | Kim | Shoes |
| UK | Tim | Kim | Bag |
| US | John | Sam | Belt |
| US | John | Sam | Bag |

The result should look like:

| Country | Agent | Customer | Products |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Country | Agent | Customer | Products |
| UK | Mo | Sara | Bag |
| UK | Adam | Jill | Bag |
| UK | Tim | Kim | Shoes, Bag |
| US | John | Sam | Belt, Bag |

I have 1 query that pull customers, products and country and another query that pulls Agent and country.  I have made Agent as my detail object associated with country.  I get following output

| Country | Agent | Customer | Products |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UK | Mo | Sara | Bag |
| UK | Adam | Jill | Bag |
| UK | Tim | Kim | Shoes |
| UK | Tim | Kim | Bag |
| US | John | Sam | Belt |
| US | John | Sam | Bag |

I tried to follow instructions from
http://bi.srivatsakr.com/2011/08/converting-rows-into-single-cell-comma.html

```
[VAR Max Products] = Max ([Products] In [Customer])
    
[VAR Concat Products] = [Products]+", "+Previous(Self)
    
[VAR Max Concat Products]= [VAR Concat Products] Where ([Products]=[VAR Max Products])
    
[VAR Product] = If(IsNull(Previous([VAR Max Concat Products]));Substr([VAR Max Concat Products];1;Length([VAR Max Concat Products])-2);Substr([VAR Max Concat Products];1;Pos([VAR Max Concat Products];Previous([VAR Max Concat Products]))-3))
```

But that give me results like

| Country | Agent | Customer | Products | [VAR Product] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UK | Mo | Sara | Bag | Bag |
| UK | Adam | Jill | Bag |  |
| UK | Tim | Kim | Shoes, | Bag, Shoes |
| UK | Tim | Kim | Bag |  |
| US | John | Sam | Belt | Bag, Belt |
| US | John | Sam | Bag |  |

If I remove the Product Column, the result is as follows:

| Country | Agent | Customer | Products | [VAR Product] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UK | Mo | Sara | Bag |  |
| UK | Adam | Jill |  |  |
| UK | Tim | Kim |  |  |
| UK | Tim | Kim |  |  |
| US | John | Sam |  |  |
| US | John | Sam |  |  |

I can hide the Product Column but it still won't show the correct result.
Need some advice. Appreciate the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I changed following these two variables and it worked fine:

```
[VAR Concat Products] = Previous(Self)+", "+[Product]
```

```
[VAR Product] = Substr([VAR Max Concat Products];3;Length(([VAR Max Concat Products])-2)
```

Comment: Could you accept your own answer to let others know that the issue is resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I converted some rows into a string based on [this SAP blog post](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/11/27/concatenating-values-of-a-column/) like this:

```
_Concat_MyField = Previous(Self) + (If IsNull(Previous(Self)) Then "" Else ", ") + [MyField]

Final = Last([_Concat_MyField] ForEach ([MyField]))
```

The `_Concat_MyField` variable joins each row with the previous row's value, and the `Final` variable grabs the last entry, which is the one where all the rows have been joined into the string.

It makes more sense if you put `[MyField]` and `[_Concat_MyField]` into the same table in a sample report.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by changing one formula:

```
[VAR Concat Products] = Previous(Self)+ (If IsNull(Previous(Self)) Then "" Else ", ") +[Products]
```

(I changed the concatenation order, and added "If" to prevent unnecessary commas)

**This breaks in long result sets.** Maximum variable length is approx. 5000 characters and the concatenation variables will get filled after a few hundred rows. Try displaying in the table the values of "Concat Products" and "Max Concat Products".